# Save columns of data from a text file as separate files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, columnsorting

I am looking for a way to take a text file that has columns of data separated by tab spaces:

file.txt

```
abcd    abcd    abcd
efgh    efgh    efgh
ijkl    ijkl    ijkl
mnop    mnop    mnop
qrst    qrst    qrst
```

And using awk I would like to save each column of data as its own text file, using numbers as file names.

but the problem is there is no way of predicting the number of columns of the text that they will contain,

The only thing I know is that the columns will be separated by tab spaces.

Such That

```
awk '{ print $1 }' file
```

will print column one

and:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' file
```

will print column two

However I am looking to save each column as is own file.

The number of columns could be anything up into the 100's

Comment: If you do not have an entry for a given column -- then what?

Comment: all columns are full and uniform in spacing

Comment: what's the expected max size (MBytes) of your input file?

Comment: you've included the tag `columnsorting` ... why? is there an additional requirement to sort the data in each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**all output files open at the same time**

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > i".out"}' file
```

**NOTES:**

- this will open, and keep open, a file descriptor for each output file
- many `awk` implementations have a limit on the number of files they can have open at a time; opening and closing files is time consuming so from a performance perspective you will want to limit the number of open and close operations
- `GNU awk` has a fairly high limit on how many files can be opened at one time
- if you have `GNU awk` and you receive an error stating something about too many open file descriptors then let us know and we can look at another idea (eg: running a separate `awk` for each set of N columns; using an in-memory solution - assuming the whole file can fit in memory)
- you mention columns are separated by `tab spaces`; (not sure what you mean ... columns are separated by multiple tabs and spaces? columns are separated by tabs or spaces?) this answer uses `awk's` default field delimiter of 'white space' (multiple spaces/tabs treated as a single delimiter); if your fields are delimited by tabs, but include spaces within the fields, then change `awk '{for ...` to `awk -F'\t' '{for ...`

**in-memory; one output file open at a time; vanilla awk**

Assuming the input file can fit into memory:

One idea that should work for all `awk` flavors:

```
awk '
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
          cols[i]=cols[i] (FNR==1 ? "" : ORS) $i
    }
END { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          outfile= i ".out"
          print cols[i] > outfile
          close(outfile)
      }
    }
' file
```

**in-memory; one output file open at a time; GNU awk**

Another in-memory solution using `GNU awk` (for multi-dimensional array support):

```
awk '
    { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
         cols[i][FNR] = $i 
    }
END { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          outfile= i ".out"
          for (j=1;j<=FNR;j++)
              print cols[i][j] > outfile
          close(outfile)
      }
    }
' file
```

All 3 of these answers generate:

```
$ head ?.out
==> 1.out <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst

==> 2.out <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst

==> 3.out <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

---

**Performance review**

Setup:

```
# create a file with 5000 lines and 500 columns; ~19.5 MBytes

awk '
BEGIN { for (i=1;i<=5000;i++) {
            printf "%s", "col_1"
            for (j=2;j<=500;j++)
                printf "\t%s", "col_" j
            print ""
        }
      }
' > multi_column.txt
```

**2.5 million open/close operations**

Running either of the 2x answers that open/close each of 500 output files, for each of 5000 input lines, (ie, `5000 x 500 = 2.5 million` open/close operations):

- killed after 2 minutes and 800 lines processed
- extrapolating: **~12.5 minutes** to process 5000 lines
- time will (obviously) vary depending on hardware (eg, Ed Morton reports his answer takes **10 minutes** on his laptop)

**all (500) output files open at the same time**

Running the 1st answer (above):

- **10 seconds** to generate 500 files with 5000 lines each
- even if we had to limit ourselves to, say, processing 20 columns at a time ... we could make 25 passes of the input file and still complete in < 7 minutes (time could be further reduced by running some of the `awk` sessions in parallel)

**in-memory; one output file open at a time; vanilla awk**

Running the 2nd answer (above)

- **6 seconds** to generate 500 files with 5000 lines each

**in-memory; one output file open at a time; GNU awk**

Running the 3rd answer (above):

- **3 seconds** to generate 500 files with 5000 lines each
- previous in-memory answer is slower due to the time required to 'find and append' the new field onto the end of the ever-increasing-in-length array entry (`cols[i]=cols[i] (FNR==1 ? "" : ORS) $i`)

Comment: The `FNR==1` test in `cols[i]=cols[i] (FNR==1 ? "" : ORS) $i` assumes that the first line has the max number of fields. Maybe it doesn't. A more robust test would be `cols[i]=(i in cols ? cols[i] ORS : "") $i`

Answer (score 1):

Portably with all awks no matter how many columns your input has:

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out = $i ".out"
        if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
            printf "" > out
        }
        print $i >> out
        close(out)
    }
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{max=NF>max ? NF : max; next} 
{for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
    fn=sprintf("%s.col", i)
    print $i >> fn
    close(fn)
    }
}' file file
```

If your column widths are uniform, you can do one pass:

```
awk 'FNR==1{max=NF}
{for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
    fn=sprintf("%s.col", i)
    print $i >> fn
    close(fn)
    }
}' file
```

Either creates these files with your example:

```
$ head *.col
==> 1.col <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst

==> 2.col <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst

==> 3.col <==
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

Comment: S?He said s?he potentially has 100's of columns. Some awks die with a dozen open files...

Answer (score 0):

Using array to avoid repeating writing process for every single line

```
awk '
        {
                for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
                  # saving columns in multi-array 
                  # i = column, NR = line
                  a[i][NR] = $(i)  
                }
        }
        END{
                # iterating through array
                for (col in a){
                 joined = ""
                 # joining lines per column
                 for (line in a[col]){
                  joined = joined a[col][line] "\n"
                 }
                 gsub(/\n$/,"",joined)
                 # write all joined lines per column at once to col-file
                 print joined > col".out"
                }
        }
' file.txt
```